# Django: How to filter django objects based on month?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to get/count how many orders that were made in a month, i have written some logic to do this, but the issue is this: It does not count how many total orders were made in a month, it spreads different orders on the same month.

To be more explicit, look at the reponse below:

**This is how to the queryset looks now**

```
<QuerySet [{'month': 4, 'count': 1}, {'month': 6, 'count': 1}, {'month': 6, 'count': 1}]>
```

**This is how to the expected queryset should look**

```
<QuerySet [{'month': 4, 'count': 1}, {'month': 6, 'count': 2}]>
```

The `'month':4` is `'month':April` and `'month':6` is `'month':June`

---

This is the code i have written to do this, but does not work

**models.py**

```
class CartOrder(models.Model):
    vendor = models.ManyToManyField(Vendor) 
    ...
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
```

**views.py**

```
import calendar
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth

orders = CartOrder.objects.annotate(month=ExtractMonth('date')).values('month').annotate(count=Count('id')).values('month','count')

print(orders)
```

terminal

```
<QuerySet [{'month': 4, 'count': 1}, {'month': 6, 'count': 1}, {'month': 6, 'count': 1}]>
```

Comment: Try https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/ like .aggregate(Sum('count'))? If it's easy to give a reproducible example (which is not) i'll experiment more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two different ways. First, in a simple way, you can just select distinct months from your object QuerySet, then filter the data set counting results per months:

```py
class ObjectsPerMonthListView(generic.ListView):
    model = CartOrder
    template_name = 'some_template.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        months = qs.values('date__month').distinct()
        data = []
        for value in months:
            count = qs.filter(date__month=value['date__month']).count()
            data.append({'month': value['date__month'], 'count': count})

        return data
```

Alternatively, in a more "advanced" way, we can use `.order_by` to [group by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-order-by) distinct values:

```py
class ObjectsPerMonthListView(generic.ListView):
    model = CartOrder
    template_name = 'some_template.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        alternative = (
            qs
            .order_by('id')
            .values('date__month')
            .annotate(count=Count('id'))
            .order_by()
        )

        return alternative
```

some_template.html

```py
<h2>Objects Per Month</h2>

{% for obj in object_list %}
    <p>{{ obj }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, my application is a non-drf application, would the same logic still aply?

Comment: You had `drf` tag in your question, so I just assumed. Anyway, query-wise it works in the same manner. I will adapt the answer as soon as I can.